# How to load an geotiff image over google map?

Tags: google-maps, geotiff

I want to load an geotiff which has tfw file also. How can i load this geotiff file to the google map in web? Please advice

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'tiff' extension supported, you can use png instead of it after convert.

Here is the link for how you can add image on google map

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple

Comment: thanks anand, but how will i get the coordinates to show that  image over the map?

Comment: Hi madhu,please refer this link

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_i_display_and_load_geotiff_images_in_web_browser_from_my_desktop_do_processing_on_itWhich_programming_language_can_be_used_for_this